# Add counting column for each categorical value in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I´m working  an oil wells database and I need to get a column counting months since first production.

Note that I need for every natural month the counting value (for instance to compare every well production level in its second month in production) so the solutions with groupby/agg are not useful in this case.

I ´ve doubts on how to achieve the desired month_count column

| id | year | month | month_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022 | 6 | 1 |
| A | 2022 | 7 | 2 |
| A | 2022 | 8 | 3 |
| A | 2022 | 9 | 4 |
| B | 2022 | 8 | 1 |
| B | 2022 | 9 | 2 |
| C | 2022 | 5 | 1 |
| C | 2022 | 6 | 2 |
| C | 2022 | 7 | 3 |
| C | 2022 | 8 | 4 |
| C | 2022 | 9 | 5 |

Here´s the code, including the desired output (month_count) column

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
    'year' : [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022],
    'month' : [6,7,8,9,8,9,5,6,7,8,9],
    'month_count' : [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5],
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which solution would be the best in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I m finding it hard to find an appropriate duplicate question for this. I m pretty sure it has been answered before. But here is the answer for this - you need to use `cumcount` with `groupby`.

```
df['month_count'] = df.groupby(['id', 'year']).cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: this answer will not aggregate across different years, if that is a requirement

Comment: @bn_ln I don't know what you meant. Do you mean cumcount should spread across years? In that case just remove 'year' from groupby?

Comment: agreed, the groupby year doesn't seem necessary